# How to GROUP BY 3 unions in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, union

I have three unions that result in a table with three different ID's being categorized by their categories.  I want to group by them so that each instance of the three ID's appear together.  For instance:

```
id
001
034
001
034
```

becomes:

```
id
001
001
034
034
```

I know I need to create an alias, but I also want to SELECT * while creating it, and then grouping them by ID.  Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you actually need here is an `ORDER BY` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT id
   FROM yourTable1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT id
   FROM yourTable2

   UNION ALL

   SELECT id
   FROM yourTable3
) Result
ORDER BY Result.Id ASC
```